Merkle Tree Correctness
This is the output for my Merkle tree. Wanted to see how it performed but this is my first time doing this. Is this valuable or can I improve its performance and tune it better some how?.
OUTPUT:
bash-4.4$ python3 classStarterCodeMerkleTree.py
Merkle Tree Root Hash: de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94
Proof for file2.txt: [('1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135', 'left'), ('3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c', 'right')]
Original file validation: True
Modified file validation: False
bash-4.4$ python3 classStarterCodeMerkleTree.py
Initialized a new Merkle Tree.
Hashed file1.txt: 1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135
Added new leaf node for file1.txt.
Starting to build/rebuild the tree...
Root of tree: LeafNode(hash_value=1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135)
Hashed file2.txt: 3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca
Added new leaf node for file2.txt.
Starting to build/rebuild the tree...
Combined hashes 1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135 and 3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca to get 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945
Created internal node with combined hash 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945 from LeafNode(hash_value=1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135) and LeafNode(hash_value=3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca).
Root of tree: InternalNode(hash_value=1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945)
Hashed file3.txt: 9b07b3f2670039e1b0d1cf62b6b328f802a12965b7cc4ccbda7c9fd122d2e05a
Added new leaf node for file3.txt.
Starting to build/rebuild the tree...
Combined hashes 1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135 and 3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca to get 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945
Created internal node with combined hash 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945 from LeafNode(hash_value=1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135) and LeafNode(hash_value=3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca).
Combined hashes 9b07b3f2670039e1b0d1cf62b6b328f802a12965b7cc4ccbda7c9fd122d2e05a and 9b07b3f2670039e1b0d1cf62b6b328f802a12965b7cc4ccbda7c9fd122d2e05a to get 3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c
Created internal node with combined hash 3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c from LeafNode(hash_value=9b07b3f2670039e1b0d1cf62b6b328f802a12965b7cc4ccbda7c9fd122d2e05a) and LeafNode(hash_value=9b07b3f2670039e1b0d1cf62b6b328f802a12965b7cc4ccbda7c9fd122d2e05a).
Combined hashes 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945 and 3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c to get de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94
Created internal node with combined hash de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94 from InternalNode(hash_value=1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945) and InternalNode(hash_value=3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c).
Root of tree: InternalNode(hash_value=de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94)
Current root hash: de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94
Merkle Tree Root Hash: de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94
Generating proof for node at index 1: LeafNode(hash_value=3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca)
Combined hashes 1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135 and 3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca to get 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945
Added to proof: ('1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135', 'left')
Combined hashes 9b07b3f2670039e1b0d1cf62b6b328f802a12965b7cc4ccbda7c9fd122d2e05a and 9b07b3f2670039e1b0d1cf62b6b328f802a12965b7cc4ccbda7c9fd122d2e05a to get 3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c
Combined hashes 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945 and 3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c to get de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94
Added to proof: ('3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c', 'right')
Proof for file2.txt: [('1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135', 'left'), ('3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c', 'right')]
Hashed file2.txt: 3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca
Starting verification with file hash 3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca
Combined hashes 1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135 and 3365c1ab99c47e5770e3bd0c08ba4a30da1d6801c4209e21b701b447404464ca to get 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945
Updated hash during verification: 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945
Combined hashes 1261a91e138d61d1307626f769e7075f00a0fd506085042145073af78923a945 and 3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c to get de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94
Updated hash during verification: de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94
Verification result: True (expected root was de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94)
Hashed modified_file2.txt: f1f6dad130c6e42bac28c51fffb1954d3c5a62355b45769c42fda5b7745db53f
Starting verification with file hash f1f6dad130c6e42bac28c51fffb1954d3c5a62355b45769c42fda5b7745db53f
Combined hashes 1c5765614f88e34d25e129536d447c45303fd0295c89e8ae6984365bb1dd1135 and f1f6dad130c6e42bac28c51fffb1954d3c5a62355b45769c42fda5b7745db53f to get d381124c01c49d926d76dc29d0b13d6dc4d9e521daa59b0872010ce08f011563
Updated hash during verification: d381124c01c49d926d76dc29d0b13d6dc4d9e521daa59b0872010ce08f011563
Combined hashes d381124c01c49d926d76dc29d0b13d6dc4d9e521daa59b0872010ce08f011563 and 3527607ce71fc0351bb2c3310f9533ecd7c8827ca7a8603e47beb0d05936eb1c to get 6e095c0efc8cc99af53c8cdeb614d57cbd660932d7c551fb08e4586637b21e94
Updated hash during verification: 6e095c0efc8cc99af53c8cdeb614d57cbd660932d7c551fb08e4586637b21e94
Verification result: False (expected root was de327709272ac6848f7da30672d14fa0ef4ca3e7c79a93abbce2b00b6c718d94)
Original file validation: True
Modified file validation: False
bash-4.4$
I tried implementing Merkle tree for the first time and I am expecting to seek more information on how to improve.
